# Perform complex AI tasks in game without multithreading

Tags: java, gwt, libgdx, artificial-intelligence, game-ai

We are developing a turn based strategy game using libGDX. We want the game to run on mobile devices and the browser. The AI of the game has to perform quite complex calculations. These calculations would freeze the game loop.

The problem is, that libGDX does not support multi threading for the GWT/Javascript backend. How would you do these complex calculations without freezing the game loop?

Comment: My (tiny amount of) experience with GWT was many years ago, but I seem to remember it being client-side, not backend. Am I remembering incorrectly? Either way, if it does not support multiple threads, drop it on the floor. I would not bother to work around it. If you truly have something heavy, you need some proper support for it. Hopefully somebody answers saying that you concurrency is in fact supported.

Comment: The use of backend here is quite ambigious. LibGDX is a game engine and you can compile for different platforms. One of them is HTML and you are using the GWT/JS "backend". The game will be running only on the clientside and we have an quite big codebase using libGDX so switching the api is not an option for us.

Comment: Ah! I see your problem more clearly now. I have heard that there are hacks for JavaScript for this kind of thing (I read about some recently in an old discussion on another site), but unfortunately I've never used JavaScript in that manner, so I cannot help. I can only offer that I have seen others claim to have multithreading hacks for JavaScript. Sorry.

Comment: This is one of those "impossible to answer" questions because the parameters are not well defined. Let me just say that if your input is distinct and your output is one of a finite number of results, the complexity of the calculation can be rendered inconsequential by storing all possible results in lookup tables, keyed to the required inputs to reach that output.

Comment: GWT has the option to use an `Scheduler`, that returns the event loop after each calculation, so the UI doesnt freeze. Not sure if its that what you are looking for but check it out: http://www.gwtproject.org/javadoc/latest/com/google/gwt/core/client/Scheduler.html#scheduleIncremental-com.google.gwt.core.client.Scheduler.RepeatingCommand-

Answer (score 0):

I think we will use one of the following libraries to implement multi threading in JS: 
1) http://extremelysatisfactorytotalitarianism.com/blog/?p=645 
2) https://github.com/tomekziel/gwtwwlinker